# Redux reducer - does it mutate the state?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I came across the following redux reducer and while it works fine, I believe it's wrong:

```
export default (state = initState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case RESET_SCREEN:
            return Object.assign({}, state, initState);
        case MODIFY_ITEM:
            let itemId = state.item.id;
            state.items[itemId].item = action.item;
            return Object.assign({}, state, {items: state.items});
    }
}
```

Is it correct that the RESET_SCREEN is good because it doesn't mutate the state, however the MODIFY_ITEM part is bad because it mutates? In which cases will it hurt? (because the app is currently behaving as expected)

What's the alternative for MODIFY_ITEM?

Comment: please show the structure of your `initState`

Answer (score 2):

> Is it correct that the RESET_SCREEN is good because it doesn't mutate
>   the state

Yes, This is correct.

> however the MODIFY_ITEM part is bad because it mutates

No, `MODIFY_ITEM` does not mutate the state:

This line: `state.items[itemId].item = action.item;` mutates the object (not the state), but `redux` does not care about local object mutation -- it would not even know.

As long as you return a new reference -- a new copy of the object, `redux` considers it a valid new state.

So, as per redux,
This is state mutation:

```
case MODIFY_ITEM:
        let itemId = state.item.id;
        state.items[itemId].item = action.item;
        return state; // <-- because you are returning the same reference. BAD
```

This is NOT state mutation:

```
case MODIFY_ITEM:
    let itemId = state.item.id;
    state.items[itemId].item = action.item;
    return Object.assign({}, state, {items: state.items}); // <- A new Object. GOOD
```

You might want to read about shallow-checking and state mutation [here](https://redux.js.org/faq/immutable-data).

Answer (score 0):

You are mutating the previous state in this line

```
state.items[itemId].item = action.item;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a npm [immer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/immer).

It is a tiny package that allows you to work with immutable state in a more convenient way. It is based on the [copy-on-write mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write).

Answer (score 0):

In order to keep the immutability of the state, you could write the `MODIFY_ITEM` action handler like this:

```
case MODIFY_ITEM:
    let itemId = state.item.id;
    return {...state, items: state.items.map((item, index) => {
        return index === itemId ? action.item : item
    })}
```

Comment: `state.items` is an object.

Comment: How do you know that ? According to the question, it could be an array of objects as well.